# What is the set where $f\left(z\right)= \left|z\right|$ is differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the set of all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ where the function $f\left(z\right)= \left|z\right|$ is differentiable.

**Remark:** I think that the function $f\left(z\right)= \left|z\right|$ is not differentiable in $\mathbb{C}$, but I could not prove it, I tried to use the fact that the function $g\left(z\right)= \left|z\right|^{2}$ is not differentiable in $\mathbb{C}$ except in $0$, but I have more complicated.

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of differentiable?

Comment: @ErickWong Yes, but the limit is complicated, it is not as easy as the function $g\left(z\right)= \left|z\right|^{2}$.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the C-R equations and first order partial derivatives of $f$ at an arbitrary point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z) = |z|$, $g(z) = z^2$. Note that $g$ is differentiable everywhere.

If $f(z) = |z|$ were differentiable, then so would be $g(f(z)) = |z|^2$, which is not if $z_0 \neq 0$. Therefore $|z|$ can't be differentiable in any point $ \neq 0$. In $0$ you don't know if it is differentiable or not, and you have to use some other methods to find out.

---

Note that the above reasoning is a little weird, it it way better to see where the CR equations are satisfied. Incidentally, if you do that, you find at once a general statement about real valued functions of complex variable (like $|z|$, $|z|^2$, etc.)